# Updating avatar file upload with validation in Laravel not showing proper response

Tags: laravel, validation, controller, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 and the user has an option to upload their avatar pic.  I am trying to set the requirement that the user has to change their avatar if it is the default one which is `"/images/company_logo_default.png"` inside the database.  For some reason it is not saving if the file is uploaded and displaying the validation messages again.

In the controller I have:

```php
 $default_avatar = "/images/company_logo_default.png";
```

I have   `'avatar' => 'required|string|not_in:'.$default_avatar,` 
within the  `$this->validate($request, [])` block and my blade file has the proper php code which is:

```php
<input id="avatar" type="hidden" class="form-control @error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror" name="avatar" value="{{ $company->avatar }}">
   @error('avatar')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
         </span>
   @enderror
```

and the messages are displayed correctly if the submit button is clicked and the user has the default profile pic but when I upload a new one it gives the message again without saving. Any help or guidance in the right direction would be helpful thanks!

Comment: please provide your controller code where you upload the file

Answer (score 0):

the ***not-in*** method accepts an array.

`$default_avatar = "/images/company_logo_default.png";` should be like

```
$default_avatar = ["/images/company_logo_default.png"`];


'avatar' => [
        'required',
        'string',
         Rule::notIn($default_avatar),
    ],
```

as it is said in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-not-in)

Comment: Thanks but for some reason this is still not working, I am updating the profile pic before the other validation is called: